# Subscription payment failed. Finish the payment using Checkout

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm building Stripe integration by using Laravel Cashier. When a user gets to the payment of the subscription I'm using Stripe Checkout for him to make the payment. When the payment fails for whatever reason, lets say 3D secure is rejected, I would like to allow the user to finish the payment. Laravel Cashier has that covered by including `cashier.payment` route which is pointing to `Laravel\Cashier\Http\Controllers\PaymentController` which will handle finishing the payment. And it works.

However I would rather use Stripe Checkout again to finish the payment. For consistency and UX reasons. Would that be possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, using Checkout Session you can't complete an existing PaymentIntent.

Alternatively, you can activate in your dashboard[1] the option to Send emails to customers to update failed card payment methods. That mail will redirect the user to a Stripe hosted invoice page in order to complete the payment.

[1] https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/billing/automatic

Comment: Would it be possible to generate the link to a Stripe hosted invoice page in order to complete the payment? It would be prefered to have a button "Finish payment" which would like to that Stripe hosted invoice page.

Comment: Stripe invoice object has property $hosted_invoice_url. Which is the link to the hosted page. Which it basically concluds it for me. If you write your comment as an anwer I will accept it as the correct answer and we can close it.

Comment: No worries about the format of the answering, the most important thing is to hear that you managed to resolve your issue :)